# How to display userid when posting comments?

Tags: support, profile-page, display-names, posts

I'm logged in yet when I post a comment, it always comes up with an artificial userisxxxxx. how to get my user name to display instead of an artificial userxxxxxx?

Comment: you might want to modify the information in this URL http://stackoverflow.com/users/1626551/user1626551

Answer (score 2):

You can change your display name by going to your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1626551/user1626551) and clicking "edit".